# Is it possible for a go binary to reload itself?

Tags: go

I'm using go-update (https://github.com/inconshreveable/go-update) to update a Go binary that I distribute to users. Right now, when the running go program detects a new version, it sends a message to the user asking them to to quit and restart the program.

Is it possible for the running go program to reload itself from the new binary?

This was asked in the go-update issue tracker, but no answer:
https://github.com/inconshreveable/go-update/issues/5

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using `os.Args` which holds the executable name of the current process, and the `os.exec` package that can start and fork processes. A good example is how it is done in the `goagain` package, which supports zero downtime restarts. In fact, you can probably just use it.

See https://github.com/rcrowley/goagain

and more specifically in this file: https://github.com/rcrowley/goagain/blob/master/goagain.go#L77

Comment: Please do realize that it's easily possible to fake the executable name in `os.Args` by the program that executed the application. This isn't a problem *per-se* but might cause security issues if the application runs with elevated permissions.

Comment: @FUZxxl I don't know of a pre-baked way to do it, but you can always use `os.GetPid()` to get our current process id, and then look up the executable path in `/proc/<pid>/exe`. And then you can make sure that this is in fact the current executable.

Comment: Well, if you like to tie yourself to Linux… this method is not really portable; most operating systems provide a way to figure out what name the binary of a running process has, but the way to do this is different on each.

Comment: @FUZxxl of course, which is why go supports _windows.go build rules, etc etc.

Comment: Notably, the package you suggest doesn't use them. I'm not really sure if Windows has a process-replacing `exec()` anyway.

Comment: @FUZxxl yes it does. of course the semantics are a bit different, and replacing an executable is not that simple because it's "locked", but it's certainly possible: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: As far as I know, Microsoft Windows' `CreateProcess` creates a new process instead of replacing an existing one and is thus not a suitable replacement for `exec()` in this context. Remember, `exec()` replaces the image of the calling process without creating a new process. To create a new process on Unix, you use `fork()`, then `exec()`.